# Does OpenWRT support 5GHz channels 50-144 on any hardware?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt

Taking United States as example.

I cannot parse [United States section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#United_States) of Wikipedia article, but, per the [5GHz table section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)) of the same article, 5GHz routers need to support both DFS and TPC in order to work on channels 50-144. Is this correct?

Do any Wi-Fi devices/drivers support both DFS and TPC? As far as I see, a lot of devices [support DFS](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/basic), but I see no meaningful mentions of TPC.

From [this discussion at OpenWRT forum](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/can-openwrt-support-802-11ac-midband-dfs-on-router-if-oem-firmware-does-not-support-it-but-underlying-chipset-and-driver-supports-it/86862/4) I conclude that DFS and TPC are only implemented in the firmware blobs of the newest hardware. Which means that it will take years to get these features to OpenWRT, and there are probably no devices that can use channels 50-144. Is this correct?

Comment: Government agencies of taken it upon themselfs to require by law, in order to sell the device in the region,m that WiFi devices only support the support channels in their region through a hardware lock. If channels 50-144 cannot be legally used in the US then they cannot be enabled on any US-based router that supports OpenWRT.

Comment: These channels can legally be used, but only in concert with DFS & TPC. // I'm voting to close this question because, while not strictly a hardware shopping question, it will soon be outdated all the same.

Comment: I see one factually incorrect comment and one comment that square-pegs the question into a "shopping" category, which it is not (arguably) - note the generality quantifier in "does OpenWRT support DFS and TPC on **ANY** hardware", and three close votes. If the close votes are based on these comments, I suggest to retract them.